# Enabling virtual hosts in Apache makes every host forbidden (403)

Tags: virtualhost, wampserver, apache2.4

I am on Windows 8 and just now installed Wamp 2.5 (Apache 2.4.9) at `C:/wamp` to test my code locally. I have my source code repository at `D:/workpace/project1` which I manage using GIT (GIT is one of the reasons I don't want to disturb its location).

After Installing Wamp, I just went on to enable virtual hosts by uncommenting the following line in `httpd.conf`.

```
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then I headed to `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` created its backup and created the virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/workspace/project1/"
    ServerName project1
    ServerAlias p1
    ErrorLog "logs/project1(local)-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project1(local)-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:/workspace/project1/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also edited the hosts file and added the necessary lines.

```
127.0.0.1       project1
127.0.0.1       p1
```

The problem is that I get `403 Forbidden` error not just when I access `project1/` and `p1/`, but also when I access `localhost/`.

When I disable httpd-vhosts.conf in httpd.conf by commenting out,

```
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I am able to access `localhost/` but as expected, `project1/` and `p1/` too resolve to `localhost/`.

Surprisingly, when I re-enable `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `httpd.conf` and restore the backup of original(unchanged) `httpd-vhosts.conf`, I still get `403 (Forbidden)` even on `localhost/`. But again when I disable `httpd-vhosts.conf`, `localhost/` comes to normal.

It is furthermore surprising to note that If I change `DocumentRoot` to a dummy folder within `c:/wamp/www`, the story is the same. So this is not just happening when `DocumentRoot` is outside `c:/wamp/www`.

I feel that I have something extra to enable because there is no chance I have messed up anything as this is a fresh installation and I have made no changes except the ones above.

What may be the reason Apache is not getting along with virtual hosts?

Comment: Just a side note: why using virtual hosts locally? Just create an `Alias` for each project and your are fine. Also no adjustment to the hosts file required...

Comment: For the virtual host issue itself: first step _always_ is to look into the http servers error log file, especially during restart time. That is where the server logs issues with its configuration. Also monitor that file while making requests, you might find additional information about issues. Do you find any additional information that might help with your problem?

Comment: @arkascha, Strange !!! ... The logs are not getting updated when `httpd-vhosts.conf` enabled ... `project1(local)-error.log` and `project1(local)-access.log` too are not created.

Comment: Ah, then most likely the name resolution does not work and your browser tries to access whatever. Check that first, easiest by using the telnet utility: `telnet project1 80` - what happens?

Comment: @arkascha, Where do I look for it ... ? I have update `hosts` file...

Comment: Said so above... Apart from that, just to be _really_ sure: you really, really, really did restart the http server after doing the modifications? And also, again just to be sure, remove those brackets (`(`/`)`) from the log file names in your configuration...

Comment: @arkascha pinging gave a positive reply ... `telnet project1 80` gave an empty screen screen and a blinking cursor for a few seconds before returning to prompt...

Comment: OK, looks like `telnet` cannot connect, which matches your observation that no log files are created. The `ping` command is more or less useless for such things. Could it be that the http server simply does not start with that configuration of yours? but that should be logged into the error log file. Note: the normal error log file of your http server, not that you expect for those virtual hosts.

Comment: @arkascha, No, without httpserver starting, how wud I even get an error?

Comment: Because it logs its startup problems. note: errors at startup time. not errors at request time. you also get log entries when the startup succeeds. Like what your system logs when booting.

Comment: @arkascha apache error log when I restarted it ... `[Sat May 30 14:29:44.672787 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5244:tid 536] AH00422: Parent:  Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat May 30 14:29:46.693901 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4772:tid 460] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat May 30 14:29:46.892912 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5244:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4772 exited successfully.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79182/discussion-between-tabrez-ahmed-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that you have not taken into account.

When you create Virtual Hosts Apache ignores the host defined in httpd.conf so you also need to create a Virtual Host for `localhost`. This explains why you cannot get to `localhost` when you have activated Virtual Hosts.

Apache is IPV4 and IPV6 aware, so when you create your domain names in the HOSTS file you need to do so for both the IPV4 and IPV6 stacks. So you would need to have a HOSTS file like this :-

```
#IPV4 Stack
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  project1

#IPV6 Stack
::1 localhost
::1 project1
```

The browser makes some arbitrary decision on whether to use the IPV4 stack or the IPV6 stack. Wish I understood why and for what reason it makes this decision better, but basically when you enter a domainname, the browser, or the networking stack, picks IPv4 or IPv6 for your first contact to a domain and then sticks to that decision, but it could use either.

Here is a post that [should help you create Virtual Hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)